Laravel Scribe documenting example array inside bodyParameters in FormRequest
I am documenting my Laravel API with Scribe
One of my api uses FormRequest which looks like this:
class StoreInvoiceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return match($this->method()) {
            // Anyone can create new record
            'POST' => true,
            // Updating must match record owner
            'PUT', 'PATCH' => $this->invoice->user_id === auth()->id(),
            // Unauthorized for everything else
            default => false,
        };
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'customer_id' => ['required', Rule::exists('customers', 'id')->where(static function ($query) {
                return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
            })],
            'customer_email_ids' => ['present', 'array'],
            'customer_email_ids.*' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::exists('emails', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('customer_id', $this->input('customer_id'));
            })],
        ];
    }

    public function bodyParameters(): array
    {
        return [
            'customer_id' => [
                'example' => 1,
            ],
            'customer_email_ids' => [
                'description' => 'Array of email IDs associated with the customer (who will receive email notifications)',
                'type' => 'array',
                'example' => [1, 2, 3],
            ],
        ];
    }
}

When the api documentation is generated, the description and example from the bodyParameters is not being used and instead, it generates the following:

I have tried various methods and none of them appears to be working, any ideas?

According to the docs array isn't a valid type. Try 'type' => int[], maybe?

That's only valid when you are using the annotation method directly on the api controller, i.e. @bodyParam customer_email_ids integer[] required Example: [4, 7] I am not able to do mix and match that with FormRequest

There is no 'type' => 'array', in the framework you're using, it's falling back to type=string. The docs say, verbatim: "array is not a supported type, and may lead to unexpected errors. You should rather define the type of the array (eg int[], string[])." have you tried that? What happens when you change [1, 2, 3] to [1, 2, 3, 4] does example change from 9 to 11? It looks like it's the string length of the array you're passing.
